# Using GHC.runGhc fails with error: "Failed to load interface for ‘GHC.Types’ no unit id matching ‘ghc-prim’ was found"

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following code, which tries to compile and print a simple expression at runtime by calling the GHC API:

```
module Main where

import GHC
import GHC.Paths as GHP
import GHC.Types
import GHC.Prim

main :: IO ()
main = do
  val <- GHC.runGhc (Just GHP.libdir) $ GHC.compileExpr "HelloWorld"
  putStrLn $ show val
```

When I try to run it, either via first compiling or directly in GHCI, it fails with a runtime error:

> Failed to load interface for ‘GHC.Types’
>
> no unit id matching ‘ghc-prim’ was found

What do I need to do to avoid this error?

I've tried with GHC 8.6 and 8.8, and both encounter the problem. I'm running it in a new stack project with only `ghc`, `ghc-prim` and `ghc-paths` installed.

Comment: How do you invoke `ghci` such that you are getting that error? Similarly for `ghc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setSessionDynFlags` to read the package database.  If you modify your definition of `main` to read:

```
main = do
  val <- GHC.runGhc (Just GHP.libdir) $ do
    setSessionDynFlags =<< getSessionDynFlags
    GHC.compileExpr "HelloWorld"
  putStrLn $ show val
```

then it generates the exception:

```
Data constructor not in scope: HelloWorld
```

which, I suppose, is what you'd expect trying to compile the expression `HelloWorld`.